# What would happen if the AutoGenerateColumns property/attribute of the DataGrid is set to True. How would this affect data binding?

Tags: wpf, binding, datagrid

What would happen if the `AutoGenerateColumns` property/attribute of
the `DataGrid` is set to `true`?

How would this affect the data binding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting AutoGenerateColumns to true will allow the grid to display **all columns** from the ItemsSource.
AutoGenerateColumns to false will display only the **mentioned** columns in the DataGrid column templates

Comment: You're always welcome. Mark as answer if it meet your requirement or up vote if it helps you.